# В меню Bootstrap не могу подкорректировать стили

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap

```css
#main-menu {
  border: none;
}

.main-head {
  background-color: #4D5B6B;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.block1 {
  line-height: 1.1;
}

.block2 {
  line-height: 1.1;
}

.block3 {
  line-height: 48px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="ru">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Menu</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">

  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

  <meta property="og:image" content="path/to/image.jpg">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- JQuery -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Header CSS (First Sections of Website: paste after release from header.min.css here) -->

</head>

<body>
  <header class="main-head">
    <div class="top-line">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 col-lg-2 block1">
            <h1>Hello</h1>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-10 col-lg-3 col-lg-push-7 block2">
            <div class="phone">+7 (495) 00-99-56</div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-7 col-lg-pull-3 block3">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="background-color: #4D5B6B;  border-color: transparent">
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <!-- Кнопка с полосочками, которая открывает меню на мобильных устройствах -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-menu">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
              </div>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-menu">
                <ul class="list-inline">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">О компании</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Оценка</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Сделки M&amp;A</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Бухгалтерские услуги</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </div>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Нужно убрать светлую полоску при разворачивании меню на малых экранах. Прошу помочь - не могу разобраться в стилях.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После выключения бордера у вас еще осталась не выключена тень. Просто добавьте в `#main-menu`

```
 box-shadow: none;


#main-menu {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!